# Unexpected spacing from output of printf

Tags: c, printf, stdout

I have the following code and am getting strange output from some prints I was using to debug, and just want to ask for sanity why it is behaving like such.

```c
int *counter(const char *filename, bool bytes_flag, bool words_flag, bool lines_flag) {
    int *counts = malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
    int line_count = 0;
    int word_count = 0;
    int byte_count = 0;
    size_t line_size = LINE_MAX;
    FILE *file_stream;
    char *line_buffer;

    printf("%d %d %d\n", line_count, word_count, byte_count);

    file_stream = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (file_stream == NULL) {
        printf("File count not be opened.\n");
    } else {
        line_buffer = (char *)malloc(line_size);
        while (getline(&line_buffer, &line_size, file_stream) != EOF) {
            if (lines_flag) {
                line_count++;
            }
            printf("LINE - %s\n", line_buffer);

            for (int i = -1; line_buffer[i] != '\n'; i++) {
                printf("%c ", line_buffer[i]);
                byte_count++;
                if (isspace(line_buffer[i]) && !isspace(line_buffer[i - 1])) {
                    word_count++;
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
            byte_count++; //Count last \n character
        }
        fclose(file_stream);
        
        printf("\n");
        printf("%d\n", line_count);
        printf("%d\n", word_count);
        printf("%d\n", byte_count);
        printf("\n");

        counts[0] = line_count;
        counts[1] = word_count;
        counts[2] = byte_count;
    }
    return counts;
}
```

My results are

```
LINE - The Project Gutenberg eBook of The Art of War

    T h e   P r o j e c t   G u t e n b e r g   e B o o k   o f   T h e   A r t   o f   W a r 
LINE -     

         
LINE - This ebook is for the use of anyone anywhere in the United States and

 T h i s   e b o o k   i s   f o r   t h e   u s e   o f   a n y o n e   a n y w h e r e   i n   t h e   U n i t e d   S t a t e s   a n d 

3
24
130
```

from the text file

```
The Project Gutenberg eBook of The Art of War
    
This ebook is for the use of anyone anywhere in the United States and
```

Note what seems to be 4 spaces on the second line. I expect that this is the culprit, but why would this be printed before the `T h e` if this line comes after the characters are printed, i.e. the next iteration?

Comment: Look at the file with a hex dump. I'll bet there are some non-printing characters at the beginning, possibly a BOM.

Comment: Change your code to print the character codes instead of the characters, then you'll know exactly what it's printing. `printf("%d ", line_buffer[i])`

Comment: Using a debugger, you could step through the code and find out exactly what it's actually doing. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Accessing `line_buffer[-1]` like you do in your for loop is UB.

Comment: See also [How to catch edge case of a buffer with only a newline or white space characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77836044/15168)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code has undefined behavior because you access bytes before the beginning of the array in

```
    for (int i = -1; line_buffer[i] != '\n'; i++)
```

Starting at `-1` makes no sense and testing `line_buffer[i - 1]` should only be done if `i > 0`.

Furthermore, you should always stop if `line_buffer[i]` is the null terminator in case the last line in the file has no trailing newline.

Testing for transitions from space to non-space is simpler.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int *counter(const char *filename, bool bytes_flag, bool words_flag, bool lines_flag) {
    int *counts = malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
    if (counts == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate memory\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    int line_count = 0;
    int word_count = 0;
    int byte_count = 0;

    printf("%d %d %d\n", line_count, word_count, byte_count);

    FILE *file_stream = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file_stream == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
    } else {
        size_t line_size = 0;
        char *line_buffer = NULL;

        while (getline(&line_buffer, &line_size, file_stream) >= 0) {
            if (lines_flag) {
                line_count++;
            }
            printf("LINE - %s\n", line_buffer);

            unsigned char last = '\n', ch;
            for (size_t i = 0; (ch = line_buffer[i]) != '\0'; i++) {
                printf("%c ", ch);
                byte_count++;
                if (!isspace(ch) && isspace(last)) {
                    word_count++;
                }
                last = ch;
            }
        }
        fclose(file_stream);
        free(line_buffer);
        
        printf("\n");
        printf("%d\n", line_count);
        printf("%d\n", word_count);
        printf("%d\n", byte_count);
        printf("\n");
    }
    counts[0] = line_count;
    counts[1] = word_count;
    counts[2] = byte_count;
    return counts;
}
```

Note however these issues:

- if the file contains embedded nulls, reading by line will cause entire sections of the file to be ignored.
- the file is open in text mode, so the byte count will be incorrect on legacy systems that perform end of line translation.
- the counts should have a larger type to accommodate for very large files.
- you only handle one of the boolean flags.  It is unclear what to do if these flags are false: should you not store the corresponding value in the returned array?

Here is a simpler version without debugging printouts:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int *counter(const char *filename, bool bytes_flag, bool words_flag, bool lines_flag) {
    int *counts = malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
    if (counts == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate memory\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    int line_count = 0;
    int word_count = 0;
    int byte_count = 0;

    FILE *file_stream = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (file_stream == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
    } else {
        int last = '\n', c;
        while ((c = getc(file_stream)) != EOF) {
            byte_count++;
            if (isspace(c)) {
                if (c == '\n')
                    line_count++;
            } else {
                if (isspace(last))
                    word_count++;
            }
            last = c;
        }
        if (last != '\n')
            line_count++;
        fclose(file_stream);

        printf("\n");
        if (lines_flag)
            printf("%d\n", line_count);
        if (words_flag)
            printf("%d\n", word_count);
        if (bytes_flag)
            printf("%d\n", byte_count);
        printf("\n");
    }
    // should we test the flags?
    counts[0] = line_count;
    counts[1] = word_count;
    counts[2] = byte_count;
    return counts;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Sorry about the unused flags, that is something I am going to implement later and I just yanked this function out of a larger file. May I ask why you choose to use a null buffer to let getline allocate the buffer itself instead of creating your own with a defined size?

Comment: @CalebRenfroe: I let `getline` handle all the allocation for simplicity.  Note also that the buffer must be freed before returning from the function.  `getline` is defined as returning `-1` upon error or end of file, not `EOF`, which is usually defined as `-1` too, but not guaranteed.