# How to catch edge case of a buffer with only a newline or whitespace characters

Tags: c

I have the following code

```c
int * counter(const char *filename, bool bytes_flag, bool words_flag, bool lines_flag){
    int * counts = malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
    int line_count = 0;
    int word_count = 0;
    int byte_count = 0;
    size_t line_size = LINE_MAX;
    FILE * file_stream;
    char * line_buffer;

    printf("%d %d %d\n", line_count, word_count, byte_count);

    file_stream = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (file_stream == NULL) {
        printf("File count not be opened.\n");
    }
    else{
        line_buffer = (char *)malloc(line_size);
        while (getline(&line_buffer, &line_size, file_stream) != EOF){

            if (lines_flag){line_count++;}

            for ( int i = -1; line_buffer[i] != '\n'; i++){
                byte_count++;
                if (isspace(line_buffer[i]) && !isspace(line_buffer[i-1])){
                    word_count++;
                }
            }
            //byte_count++;//Count last \n character
        }
        fclose(file_stream);
        
        printf("\n");
        printf("%d\n", line_count);
        printf("%d\n", word_count);
        printf("%d\n", byte_count);
        printf("\n");

        counts[0] = line_count;
        counts[1] = word_count;
        counts[2] = byte_count;
    }
    return counts;
}
```

I am inputting the following file

```
The Project Gutenberg eBook of The Art of War
    
This ebook is for the use of anyone anywhere in the United States and
```

And my output is almost what I want, but the word count is 1 too high. This is happening because of the empty line on line 2 of the text file.

```
./ccwc.o -l small.txt
0 0 0

3
24
127
```

How could I improve

```
if (isspace(line_buffer[i]) && !isspace(line_buffer[i-1])){
    word_count++;
}
```

to catch this edge case?

Comment: The best word-counting code I've ever see uses a finite-state machine. Your `for` loop has serious problems. First iteration: [i-1] will try to access the -2th character in `line_buffer`.

Comment: `line_buffer[i]` is out of bounds on the first iteration and `line_buffer[i-1]` is out of bounds on the first two iterations. https://godbolt.org/z/MEb95Tqrz

Comment: Precise definition of your terms is important.  Is "" a line what about " " or "\n"?  Is "" a word, what about "a" or " a"?

Comment: See also [Unexpected spacing from output of `printf()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77835947/15168)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count the number of *words*, count the transitions from white-space to non-white-space.
Using a separate variable to record the prior character simplifies edge cases.

`is...()` functions expect an `unsigned char` value or `EOF`.

Note: `fgets()` may return a buffer without a `'\n'` in it.

```
        unsigned char *s = (unsigned char *) line_buffer;
        unsigned char prior = ' ';
        while (*s != '\n' && *s) {
          byte_count++;
          if (isspace(prior) && !isspace(*s)) {
            word_count++;
          }
          prior = *s;
          s++;
        }
```